# Saving an int16 stacked tif in matlab

Tags: matlab, tiff, imread

I'm trying to save a .tif in matlab. Imwrite doesn't support writing int16 directly for .tif, but it is possible to cast my picture to uint16 and use imwrite.

```
imageName='someimage.tif';
info=imfinfo(imageName);
num_images=numel(info);
x_size=info(1).Width;
y_size=info(1).Height;

result=zeros(y_size, x_size, num_images, 'uint16');
for i=1:num_images
    result(:,:,i) = im2uint16(imread(imageName,i,'Info',info));
end

imwrite(result(:,:,i), 'newimage.tif');
for i=2:num_images,
    imwrite(result(:,:,i), 'newimage.tif', 'WriteMode', 'append');
end
```

When I do this it seems like the contrast is increased somehow, while I would expect the pictures to be identical.

Secondly I tried using [this](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/35684-save-and-load-data-as-multi-frame-tiff-format) as following

```
imageName='someimage.tif';
info=imfinfo(imageName);
num_images=numel(info);
x_size=info(1).Width;
y_size=info(1).Height;

result=zeros(y_size, x_size, num_images, 'int16');
for i=1:num_images
    result(:,:,i) = imread(imageName,i,'Info',info);
end
options.message=true;
saveastiff(result, 'newimage.tif', options);
```

I have the same issue here, the contrast goes up and it ruins the picture. The pictures I am working on a grayscale.
Is there a way to save these pictures without ruining it?

Comment: Could you provide an example image?

Comment: Are you sure this is related to `int16`/`uint16` and not something like the color profile or gamma settings that `imwrite` might be applying? When you say " it seems like the contrast is increased somehow," what software are you using to view the images? Matlab, or some other image editor/viewer?

Comment: @Daniel [Here's](http://imgur.com/Ek6j7Ie,OPu3lgV#1) the original first frame and [this](http://imgur.com/Ek6j7Ie,OPu3lgV#0) is how it looks after running it through the code above.

Comment: @Locus: These are pngs, please provide the original tif which allows to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @horchler matlab's IMWRITE is pretty clear on how it feels about int16, "Writing int16 image data to a TIFF file is not supported with IMWRITE.".  It could be that there's some other setting that is interfering, but I haven't found a likely perpetrator yet.

Comment: @Daniel [This](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4216768/original.tif) is the best I can do, couldn't find a hostsite that doesn't change the file to .png.

Comment: dropbox, google drive, some arbitrary free webspace, skydrive only to mention some.

Comment: @Daniel Just to clear up a potential misunderstanding, by "this" I meant the link in my last comment (which is dropbox)

Comment: @Locus: Totally missed the link, will take a closer look at it.

Comment: @Locus: I'm confused. Was your comment reply to me meant for someone else? It seems to have nothing to do with my first comment above about the contrast changing. Or at least you didn't answer my specific questions.

Comment: The original.tif file you liked to in the comments above doesn't appear to be a layered/stacked TIFF (`num_images` is `1` and thus `info(2).Height` produces an error). Is this the same file as the `'someimage.tif'` in your code?

Comment: @horchler I'm sorry, I edited my reply but it must have disappeard because of the 5 minute rule. I'm using imagej/FIJI to view the images before and after. If I use imshow(result(:,:,1), []) it looks the same as when I open newimage.tif in imagej.
I fixed the code so it now works on original.tif, the stack of tifs is too big to upload.
Is there something else I haven't answered properly?

Comment: Read this and see if it provides a few hints. Your cast is increasing the dynamic range of the image and you'll need to scale the values to compensate.
http://www.svi.nl/TiffScaling

Comment: @siliconwafer it seems your are right. I've experimentet some and it seems like having the range [0, 2^11] imshow() will display something similar to what I want. I just pulled that number from my behind though. Is there a way to find the 'correct' answer?

Comment: @Locus perhaps. You might need to determine the range of values allowed by the original format, and then determine the range of values in your image. Then, scale those to match the range allowed by uint16. That should preserve the dynamic range of the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@siliconwafer helped me understand that my problem is that the first few frames are fairly bright and the rest of the pictures appear black if you use the same dynamic range as for the first picture.

I was not able to solve this in an eloquent way, but I did the following

```
t = Tiff("Some_image.tif", 'r+');
imgs = zeros(y_size, x_size, num_images, 'uint16');
for k=1:num_images,
    t.setDirectory(k);
    imgs(:,:,k) = t.read();
end

result = doStuff(imgs)

for k=1:num_images,
    t.setDirectory(k);
    t.write(imgs(:,:,k));
end
```

The downside of this is that it changes the picture in place. The advantage is that the dynamic range for each frame does not change.